# How do I create a single column of a vertical group in SQL (SQL Server) formatted like Excel does with Pivot tables?

Tags: sql-server, excel, formatting, pivot, grouping

I have data like this:

From MS on Excel Pivot:

[image]

I need to display the data from my table in SQL Server like the image in the bottom pane.  I have searched all over SO for the answer.  I have tried CTE, Pivot, Unpivot, Lag, and various other sundries.

Outside of using Excel or a Report for grouping in SSRS, I cannot display the data the way I need to:

I have two columns, districts and stores:

```
district   store
--------   -----
district1  store1
district1  store2
district2  store3
district2  store4
district2  store5
district3  store6
```

I used this to get the first part of my results:

```
;with my_locations as
(

    select 
        case 
            when rn = 1 then district
            when rn != 1 not null then ''
        end as district_area
        ,   store
    from (
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by district order by district) as rn
        ,   district
        ,   store
        from all_areas  --data from original table
    ) t
) 
select * from my_locations
```

which gives me:

```
district   store
--------   -----
district1  store1
NULL       store2
district2  store3
NULL       store4
NULL       store5
district3  store6
```

But, I cannot get this into anything that looks like the Excel pivot.  I want to have this in a *single* column:

```
column1
-------
district1
store1
store2
district2
store3
store4
store5
district3
store6
```

I thought I might be able to do an insert after each CASE, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this to solve it:

```
    case 
        when rn = 1 then district +  CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + store
        else store
    end as district_area
```

Full query:

```
;with my_locations as
(

    select 
        case 
            when rn = 1 then district +  CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + store
            else store
        end as district_area
    from (
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by district order by district) as rn
        ,   district
        ,   store
        from all_areas  --data from original table
    ) t
) 
select * from my_locations
```

I retain the CRLF where I copy my data to, so it comes out looking like I need.  Not exactly what I was looking for, but it is a matter or formatting.